# checking if key exists in php associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

i've this simple associative array in my php application
`

```
<?php
    $my_array => array(
       'gender'=>array('male','female'),
       'age_group'=>array('0-7','8-15','16-18','18-24'),
       'language'=>array('english','hindi')
    );
?>
```

`

i've to url like this `www.example.com/gender/male or www.example.com/age_group/0-7` now i'm able to use this function `array_key_exists()` to find whether `gender,age_group,language` key exists but i'm not able to find whether `male,female or hindi` keys exists, how to find that those key exists or not?

Comment: How about [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function?

Comment: Those aren't keys. They're VALUES. `array('a', 'b')` is the functional equivalent of `array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b')`

Comment: @undone lol i wasn’t aware about that function, thanks :)

Comment: Misleading title - This question is about values.